# onChange on checkbox doesn't fire in react

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok before deciding to publish this question I searched a lot and tried lots of things so here is the case I have

```
<div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label htmlFor="test" className="btn win-checkbox-btn" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
  <input id="test" autoComplete="off" className="taggable" type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={(e) => { console.log(e) }} />
 someText
 </label>
 <input autoComplete="off" className="taggable" type="checkbox" name="test2" onChange={(e) => { console.log(e) }} />
</div>
```

So what happens here is that the onChange function on the first checkbox (the one inside the label with the name of test) doesn't fire at all, but the onChange function on the second checkbox (test2) fire normally. I need it inside the label because i'm using [Bootstrap checkbox buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) . so Im using bootstrap 3.3.7 and react 15.6.0 .
More info is that using the htmlFor attribute on the label or removing it doesn't affect anything, and the onClick handler that I'm using on the label was in a solution I found while i was searching but also didn't help at all and removing it or adding it doesn't affect anything.

Any clue here would really help much, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe because of `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` ? What if you remove it?

Comment: I said in the post that removing that or adding it doesn't affect much, it was just a solution if found and thought it may help

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox should not be in within the label tag because label tag handles the click event in your code. Do you need at all this onclick event "onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}" on the label?

You may try following code instead: 

    `<label htmlFor="test" >someText </label>
    <input id="test" autoComplete="off" type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={(e) => { console.log(e) }} />`

Comment: Ok moving it out from the label and removing `data-toggle="buttons"` attr from the parent do solve it but then the bootstrap checkbox button that adds the class active to the label stop working which doesn't serve what i need here. _i'm thinking out loud now_ I can handle the class change by assign the class or remove it with a state i save and edit on change, but i have tons of checkboxes like that which means tons of states, I don't feel that is the optimal solution here. but thanks a lot, that at least lead to something